# Sorting numbers as I get them dynamically from a stream

Tags: sorting, dynamic, stream, mergesort

What algorithm should I use to sort numbers (in an array) as I get the numbers from a stream dynamically?

Should I just create a Hash, then merge sort?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need the array to be sorted continually, you should use Insertion-Sort algorithm each time a number is entered. Check the [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Insertion_sort) for more information. If not, you can just receive all the numbers from the input and perform, once you received all the numbers, merge sort, as you suggested.